# Alter django rest framework field before serialization and deserialization

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

what I'm trying to do, is to convert unix_epoch into python dateTime and vice versa while serialization and desiarilization. What I've done so far:

My model Track:

```
class Track(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(null=True)
    distance = models.FloatField(null=True)
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    dateClosed = models.DateTimeField(null=True)


    def date_created_to_epoch(self):
        return time.mktime(self.dateCreated.timetuple())

    def date_closed_to_epoch(self):
        return time.mktime(self.dateClosed.timetuple())
```

My model Point:

```
class Point(models.Model):

    uuid = models.UUIDField(null=True)
    track_uuid = models.UUIDField(null=True)
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(null=True);
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track, related_name='points')

    def date_created_to_epoch(self):
        return time.mktime(self.dateCreated.timetuple())
```

My serializers:

```
class PointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dateCreated = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='date_created_to_epoch')

    class Meta:
        model = Point
        fields = ('uuid', 'lat', 'lng')


class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    points = PointSerializer(many=True)
    dateCreated = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='date_created_to_epoch')
    dateClosed = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='date_closed_to_epoch')

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('uuid', 'distance', 'dateCreated', 'dateClosed', 'comments', 'type', 'status', 'points')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        points_data = validated_data.pop('points')
        track = Track.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for point_data in points_data:
            Point.objects.create(track=track, **point_data)
        return track
```

As you see, I've made from database to json convertion with def date_created_to_epoch(self): method. What I need is to implement json(unix time) to database (date time) convertion. I use nested models. I think my methods are incorrect and there is a way to make it better. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Django Rest Framework's [built in DateTime fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#date-and-time-fields) instead of the raw `.ReadOnlyField`.   You can make any field readonly by passing `read_only=True` to the field's constructor.